# Immutable as React state

Tags: reactjs, immutable.js

Is this a good solution?
https://github.com/immutable-js/immutable-js/wiki/Immutable-as-React-state

I need to put nested objects in my state.  This solution seems simple enough in code, but I'm wondering if there are any reasons not to take this approach.

Comment: react state is meant to be immutable, since react internaly compares the references not the content (for one reason because it is faster). So yes having immutable state is the way to go, if you dont understand what immutable means or you need sth else, please clarify your question

Comment: immutable library simply creates a new instance of object or array when its contents get updated and/or inserted/deleted (instead of altering same instance). There is nothing magical, you can use sth similar. Nested objects will have to create a new instance as a whole, or maybe it is better to have as separate fields of the global state and update them by themselsves (as immutable of course)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TL/DR: I recommend immutable for anything bigger than a simple news-list, together with redux-saga. But I would and don't use it for component's local state.

We have a big React app (JS, not TypeScript) that has all the state as Immutable objects.
The recommendation usually is the same as with redux and redux-saga: If you don't know why you need it, you probably don't. But here is the thing, if you start without it and later notice that it *would* be helpful, you are already deep in a mess and it's hard to switch over.

Immutable doesn't add obvious business value, but it reduces the chances of bugs and prevents you from doing things that might look good now but in the long run increase the cost of development. Especially when your dev team isn't an experienced bunch of seniors or generally tends to not strictly follow rules.

However, in my opinion, it is unecessary overkill for an components internal state, at least if business state is stored in your global redux state.

PS: Immutable is mature and probably doesn't need patches much, but it has to be said: Development of immutable essentially is stopped, they are discussing to bring in new people but who knows how that turns out. There are similar libraries which are more active

Comment: That's pretty much the conclusion I've come to as well.  Thanks, dube.